# Symlink OpenCV with multiple Virtual environments of python?

Tags: opencv, symlink

I have OpenCv 4 installed and SymLinked it to a python virtual environment, is it possible to symlink opencv to multiple virtual environments ?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Nope, did not find a solution for this